# Create Pressure on Kubernetes Nodes

Tags: linux, kubernetes, containers

I want to test Pod eviction events that caused by memorypressure for taintbasedeviction on my pods, for to do that I created a memory load on my instance that have 2 vcpu and 8GB Ram.

For create a load I have run this command :

```
stress-ng --vm 2 --vm-bytes 10G --timeout 60s
```

Output of memory usage

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.8Gi       2.7Gi       1.0Gi       3.9Gi       4.1Gi       984Mi
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

But in my nodes states there is no memorypressure I have updated kubelet eviction parameters at below :

```
evictionHard:
    memory.available:  "200Mi"
```

As summary, How Can I create memory pressure on my worker nodes for test the taint based eviction ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could invoke the stress command multiple times. Check the script [here](https://github.com/giantswarm/kube-stresscheck).

The value for `memory.available` is derived from the cgroupfs instead of tools like `free -m`. This is important because `free -m` does not work in a container, and if users use the node allocatable feature, out of resource decisions are made local to the end user Pod part of the cgroup hierarchy as well as the root node. This [script](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/memory-available.sh) reproduces the same set of steps that the kubelet performs to calculate `memory.available`. The kubelet excludes inactive_file (i.e. # of bytes of file-backed memory on inactive LRU list) from its calculation as it assumes that memory is reclaimable under pressure.

Answer (score 0):

### Question

> How Can I create memory pressure on my worker nodes for test the taint
> based eviction ?

### Answer

##### Background - Linux

Your nodes running on Linux so in general, the ad hoc approach can be to use a libray like [Stress-ng](https://stress-ng).

You can see some nice examples in the Ubuntu [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Reference/stress-ng#Forcing_memory_pressure) (not only for Ubuntu).

##### K8S

Because you're running in K8S, **it is better to use tools from the Cloud native ecosystem** that are more suitable and are integrating with K8S smoothly.
You can take a Chaos testing tool like [Chaos mesh](https://chaos-mesh.org/) that is using the Stress-ng library to simulate stress scenarios on the host.

An example from [here](https://chaos-mesh.org/docs/simulate-heavy-stress-in-physical-nodes/#example-for-simulating-memory-stress):

```
chaosd attack stress mem --workers 2 --size 100M
```

For additional reading, please also read this blog:

[How to efficiently stress test Pod memory](https://chaos-mesh.org/blog/how-to-efficiently-stress-test-pod-memory/#how-we-implement-stresschaos)